# Problems with python, customtkinter

Tags: python

Code:

```
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter import *

def createCardFunc():

    def createFunc():
        title = titleEntry.get()
        description = descEntry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        cc.destroy()

        r = CTk()

        r.geometry(f"1500x850")
        r.title("NH - Create Note")
        r.iconbitmap("Assets/Images/Logo/nh-iconbitmap.ico")
        r.resizable(False, False)

        titleLabel = CTkLabel(r, text=title, font=("Calibri", 30, 'bold'))
        titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

        r.mainloop()

    cc = CTk()
    cc.iconbitmap("Assets/Images/Logo/nh-iconbitmap.ico")
    cc.title("NH - Create Card")
    screen_width = 500
    screen_height = 500
    cc.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
    cc.resizable(False, False)

    addTitle = CTkLabel(cc, text="Title:", font=("Calibri", 25))
    addTitle.grid(row=0, column=0)

    titleEntry = CTkEntry(cc, font=("Courier New", 20, 'bold'), width=screen_width - 125)
    titleEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    descLab = CTkLabel(cc, text="Description:", font=("Calibri", 25))
    descLab.grid(row=1, column=0)

    descEntry = CTkTextbox(cc, font=("Courier New", 20, 'bold'), width=(screen_width // 2) + 108, wrap="word")
    descEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w", padx=(10, 0))

    submit = CTkButton(cc, text="Create", font=("Calibri", 20), command=createFunc)
    submit.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w", padx=(10, 0), pady=(70, 0))

    cc.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    createCardFunc()
```

Error:

```
invalid command name "3115937643968update"
    while executing
"3115937643968update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "3115937643584check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"3115937643584check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "3115937641664_click_animation"
    while executing
"3115937641664_click_animation"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "3115897138688<lambda>"
    while executing
"3115897138688<lambda>"
    ("after" script)
```

As you can see, I added some widgets to the "r" root. Whenever I run the command, no widgets appear.

The error only appears when I click the "submit" button.

I tried reinstalling customtkinter, restarting my computer,
nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the creation of a new window in the createFunc function: like said here: [Can you have two instances of tkinter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421508/can-you-have-two-instances-of-tkinter-in-python), you can't use two instances of `CTk` at the same time (Tk and CTk work the same).

You should use a `TopLevel` (or if you really don't want to you could start another python script but it is not recommended) to do what you are trying to do.

Hope I helped you, have a nice day.

**Watch the comments to see what really was the problem and the answer**

Comment: Nope. I used Toplevel and still the same error.

Comment: Oh yes it doesn't I work didn't notice sorry: a TopLevel needs a master to work.

I don't understand what you are trying to do: why do you want to destroy the main window and create a new one, couldn't you destroy all the widgets in the main window, rename the window and create new widgets instead ?

Comment: Oh yeah, great idea! I could rename the window, and destroy all widgets there, and add new ones! Thank you for the idea! I think "label.destroy()" or "root.destroy(label)" would work. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the question as solved if you have no more problems ;)